# Append to iframe src only when options are selected from drop-down

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I'm trying to construct a URL based on the options selected from 4 form input fields, 2 are select boxes, 2 are text input boxes to enter a search query. I'm using the following function.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function jobsubmit() {
    $('#frame1').attr('src','https://myurl.com/&filters=' + 
    'sector|' + $('#sector').val() + ',' +
    'worktype|' + $('#worktype').val() + ',' +
    'location|' + $('#location').val() + ',' +
    'keywords|' +  $('#keywords').val());   
}
</script>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to update the above code so that the 4 above filters (sector, worktype, location, keywords) are added ONLY if their options have been selected from the drop down.

Right now, I'm getting the following (suppose that worktype was selected):

```
https://myurl.com&filters=sector|,worktype|Contract,location|,keywords|
```

What I really need is this:

```
https://myurl.com&filters=worktype|Contract,
```

Then, if another option is selected after the first one, the URL should build onto itself like this:

```
https://myurl.com&filters=sector|Marketing,worktype|Contract,
```

And so on. What am I missing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and most extensible way to achieve this would be to put a common class on all the filter value controls. Then you can use `map()` to create an array containing only the entered values, using the `id` of the control within the filter string as in your example. Finally, you can `join()` this array back together and concatenate it with the URL string to set as the `src` of the `iframe`. Try this:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var filters = $('.filter').map(function() {
    return this.value.trim() ? this.id + '|' + this.value.trim() : null;
  }).get();
  var url = 'https://myurl.com/&filters=' + filters.join(',');

  console.log(url);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" value="foo" id="sector" class="filter" />
  <input type="text" value="" id="worktype" class="filter" />
  <input type="text" value="" id="location" class="filter" />
  <input type="text" value="bar" id="keywords" class="filter" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

> This seems to be based on form field input boxes and not drop-down/select option boxes. Trying to get this to work with drop-downs that don't require a button to submit the change

In that case hook to the `change` event on all the `select` elements instead of the `submit` of the `form`:

```js
$('.filter').on('change', function() {
  var filters = $('.filter').map(function() {
    return this.value.trim() ? this.id + '|' + this.value.trim() : null;
  }).get();
  var url = 'https://myurl.com/&filters=' + filters.join(',');

  console.log(url);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <select id="sector" class="filter">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
    <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
  </select>
  <select id="worktype" class="filter">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
    <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
  </select>
  <select id="location" class="filter">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
    <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
  </select>
  <select id="keywords" class="filter">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
    <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. However this seems to be based on form field input boxes and not drop-down/select option boxes. Trying to get this to work with drop-downs that don't require a button to submit the change. As soon as someone selects an option from either of the 2 "sector" or "worktype" drop downs, the URL should update immediately.

Comment: Sorry, trying to just create a new page with the code you provided, as is, and get this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. Refers to the `$('.filter')` part. Error disappears when I put the jQuery include before the function, but then nothing seems to work (although running the code snippet on stackoverflow seems perfect!) Just trying to get it to work locally.

Comment: You need to include jquery.js before this logic. If this causes other things to stop working then you have an error somewhere. Check the console.

Comment: Well, yes, as I said, moving the jQuery.min include BEFORE the script removed the error, but then nothing happens when I select options, and there's no output to the console :(

Comment: Unfortunately that sounds like an issue somewhere else in your logic, as you can see that this works fine in isolation from the snippet above. I'd suggest starting a new question with all relevant code if you're struggling to debug the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark this answer as correct since it seems to do what I want in the code snippet, but I have to get it working on my end :)

Comment: Got it to work! But sorry... If I then need to apply the resulting URL back into an iframe, what would the correct syntax be? `<iframe id="frame1" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="1000" height="780" src="url-from-function"></iframe>` Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I think it's just this:
`$('#frame1').attr('src', url);`

Answer (score 0):

checks if the element has a value

```
function getFilter (elemname ) {
  var _val = $('#sector').val().trim();
  return _val != "" ? elemname + "|" + _val + "," : "";
}
function jobsubmit() {
    var _url = 'https://myurl.com/&filters=' + 
    getFilter('sector') +
    getFilter('worktype') +
    getFilter('location') +
    getFilter('keywords');
    // Remove the last comma if you want.
    $('#frame1').attr('src', _url.replace(/,\s*$/, ""))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be a syntax error in the above: 
`return _val != "" ? elemname + "|" + _val + ",";` (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;). Also how does the getFilter function grab the values entered by the other 3 fields/drop-downs?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer just to show how to break a bigger problem into smaller more readable chunks of code.

```js
//function jobsubmit() {
//    $('#frame1').attr('src', buildUrl())  
//}

function buildUrl() {
   return 'https://myurl.com/?filters=' + buildFilters()
}

function buildFilters() {
    return ['sector', 'worktype', 'location', 'keywords']
       .map(maybeFilter)
       .filter(v => v !== '') // remove empty strings
       .join(',')
}

function maybeFilter(selectorId) {
    const value = getSelectorValueById(selectorId)

    if(!hasValue(value)) {
      return ''
    }

    return `${selectorId}|${value}`
}

function getSelectorValueById(selectorId) {
    return $(`#${selectorId}`).val()
}

function hasValue(value) {
    return value !== null && value !== undefined && value.trim() !== ''
}

function runExample() {
    console.log(buildUrl())
}

$('.filter').on('change', runExample)

runExample()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sector" class="filter">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option selected value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
    <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
  </select>
  <select id="worktype" class="filter">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option selected value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
    <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
  </select>
  <select id="location" class="filter">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option selected value="fizz">Fizz</option>
    <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
  </select>
  <select id="keywords" class="filter">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
    <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
  </select>
```